# How to change password reset messages in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

How to change laravel's "The email field is required." on password reset page to my custom message? Cant find rules and messages for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default messages for Laravel 5 are stored in `/resources/lang/en/passwords.php`.

Remember that you can also always override these with custom messages when validating. Check out [the documentation for the validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages).